# Проблема с тенями и светом

Tags: unity3d

**Ситуация следующая:**
Сделал сценку, террейн, расставил объекты, добавил свет, тени и т.д.
Но возникла проблема, без теней показывает `60тыс. Tris (треугольников)`.
Как только врубаю тени, показывает `250тыс.` - это никуда не годится.

Без теней все выглядит не живое и не эстетично.
В чем собственно проблема и почему так происходит и как с этим бороться?

Comment: Использовать deffered rendering.

Comment: Мне, к сожалению, лень писать ответ. Просто гуглите Deffered Rendering, [вот вам минимальный стартовый набор знаний](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RenderTech-DeferredShading.html), в двух словах это не объяснить.

Comment: Ну и в сторону Shadow Cascades надо смотреть. Оптимизация - штука замысловатая. Если совсем вкратце, то каждый источник света == еще одна камера, которая рендерит специальные теневые карты, с помощью которых просчитываются конечные тени. Поэтому и кол-во "треугольников" больше.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, поставил `deffered` снизилось до 160 тыс, это все равно много,  `Shadow Cascades` отключал. менял, ничего не меняется. Что можно еще сделать или предпринять?

Comment: Отключать тени на определенном расстоянии, реализовать окклюзию невидимых для камеры объектов или просто смириться с ситуацией. С чего вы взяли, что 160 тысяч треугольников - это проблема?

Comment: Можно еще отключить тени на незначительных объектах - всякой мелочевки, тени которой не заметишь. При этом свет они все равно будут ловить.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, проблема, это было сделано ради теста, пустая сцена 1.7к трисов, добавляю 1 модель 71 тыс трисов. и получаю 280+ тыс трисов. Это не проблема? окай, 160 теперь, 1 объект на сцене епта. А где почитать. как отключать тень с определенных объектов, я пытался найти инфу, не смог, кстати, а когда делаю оклюзию, у меня зашкаливают трисы за 600 тыс.... Чуш творится какая-то.

Comment: В "пустой" сцене не может быть треугольников вовсе. Очевидно, у вас есть 1 источник света и камера, от этого все меши, попадающие в камеру и под источник света будут рендериться 2 раза, отсюда: `71к + 71к + всякое = ~160к`. Нет, это не проблема для такой сложной модели, отсюда возникает вопрос: а зачем вам такая огромная модель? На дальнем расстоянии вы столько полигонов все равно не увидите, а вблизи можно использовать тесселяцию.

Comment: Если этот объект - какая-то большая структура/карта/etc - разбейте ее на подобъекты, в связке со встроенным frustum culling и какой-то реализацией occlusion culling это даст сильный прирост. Но вот если нужно всю модель держать в объективе и иметь источники света - никак 71к * 2 полигонов этой модели не уменьшить без способов выше. Грубо говоря, вы хотите отрендерить только часть полигонов модели - это невозможно из-за того, как устроен пайплайн GPU.

Comment: Тени можно отключить в настройках шейдера, либо вообще написать свой без поддержки теней и использовать его на определенных объектах. Вы делаете occlusion culling и у вас кол-во отрисованных полигонов увеличивается? В бесплатной Unity нет такого кулинга, вы уверены, что вы именно  **кулинг** используете? Или это стороннее решение? Приведите, пожалуйста, **всю** информацию в вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, ценю ваше время и помощь, попробую разобраться, хотя бы малость, если что-то не смогу, постараюсь детально описать в вопрос.

Comment: @RiotBr3aker, чувачек, ты гений, с твоими наводками, нашел супер метод с сокрытием, то есть не будут появляться сразу, а только в зоне видимости.

Comment: И все же настоятельно советую вас дополнить вопрос всей информацией, чтобы я или вы сами дали на него ответ. Помните, этот вопрос может помочь другим людям.